# Silex add web profiler toolbar to all request

Tags: php, symfony, profiler, silex, service-provider

In my silex application I have monolog, and profiler working together and am using https://github.com/silexphp/Silex-WebProfiler for the web profiler provider.

I can access the data by going to the routes it mounts but I would like to add the toolbar it makes too my other pages. Any idea on how I can do this?

Comment: How do you register the provider? Is your response text/html?

Comment: The way it is registered is a bit complex. Essentailly I am bootstrapping it and setting up caching etc. and will clean things up when i figure it all out. https://github.com/yamiko-org/masonary is the git account.

I am currently registering it in Masonary.php on my local machine I am trying to refactor into the bootstrap classes like the others but am having trouble with this one

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your setup. This is how I register the profiler in my silex projects: https://github.com/insolis/silex-alap/blob/master/app/bootstrap.php#L75

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was caused by a bug. There has been quite a few bugs for the web profiler caused by its dependencies being updated.